# How to use Python to create interactive plots under Orange?

Tags: python, scatter-plot, orange

I would like to use Orange to create a 3D scatterplot but apparently this feature has not yet been implemented (although it was recently requested: see [here](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/5546)).

I started playing with the Python script "widget".

I managed to create a plot that I could later save to a png image:

```
from Orange.preprocess import DomainDiscretizer
discretizer = DomainDiscretizer()
d_test = discretizer(in_data)
print(d_test[1].values)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(d_test[1].values,d_test[2].values)

plt.savefig('testplot.png')
```

However, I cannot create an interactive plot.
Under **Spyder** or **Jupyter**, I would simply type `%matplotlib` to use the Qt5Agg backend, but doing so in the Orange console returns the following error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How can I create an interactive plot using the Python widget in **Orange**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand what you mean by the interactive plot. but maybe you are talking about :

```
plt.show()
```

is that it ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sbabti, this did the trick!